# How to use check multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if-statement: if all the properties of an object have values, then the next button will be enabled.

```
const handleButton = () => {
  if(
        values.streetAdress !== ""
     && values.postalCode !== ""
     && values.city !== ""
     && values.sex !== ""
     && values.birthName !== ""
     && values.birthPlace !== ""
     && values.birthday !== ""
     && values.country !== ""
     && values.family !== ""
     && values.insuranceID !== ""
  ){
    setDisabeld(false)
  }else{
    setDisabeld(true)
  }
```

Is there a way to shorten this expression, so all properties will be checked at once?

Comment: Would something like `Object.values(values).every(x => x !== '')` work? Or do you specifically wanting something using spread syntax?

Comment: 1. if is not a function. 2. Even if it was a function it would take only one argument so spread has no reason to work.

Comment: Spread isn't helpful for this, no. But separately: The code you have is clear, easily debugged, easily updated, and easily minified by tools, and if you ever start using types, easily typechecked. You *can* make it shorter, but it's going to compromise one or more of those features.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes DRY can hurt maintainability and readability.

Comment: Three things I would change, though: 1. I'd spell "disabled" correctly (it's `led` at the end, not `eld`). 2. I'd use the boolean from the comparisons directly: `const enabled = values.streetAddress !== "" && /*...*/; setDisabled(!enabled);` 3. I'd probably express the condition differently: `const disabled = values.streetAddress === "" || /*...*/; setDisabled(disabled);` 2 & 3 are mostly a matter of preference, though.

Comment: Spread operator is not solution to this problem. if your object keys are matching with your filtering conditions, you can use @Yarin's answer. Also one more reminder, currently you are only checking if the values are not an empty string. I can recommend to add "undefined" and "null" as well just to be sure

Comment: Are you for sure trying to check **all** property names?  Is it possible that `values` may have some properties other than the ones you are checking? (maybe there are some properties irrelevant to this particular check that would make `Object.values(values)` include irrelevant properties?)  Do you have an array of the relevant property names somewhere, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method on the values of the object.

```js
const isNotEmpty = Object.values(values).every((v) => v !== '')
if(isNotEmpty) {
    setDisabeld(false)
} else{
    setDisabeld(true)
}
```

Comment: Or like @T.J.Crowder suggested `setDisabled(!isNotEmpty)`